# Convert data to a datavalue code in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to convert two columns (`year` and `month`) into a datevalue code and, in another sheet, convert a `begin_date` and `end_date` into a datevalue as code aswell.
For example convert `year` = 2017 and `month` = 4 into `4/2017` and then into `42736` (which is the datevalue code that represents that data).

In this first case, and since there are two separate columns, `year` and `month`, i tried to convert them into the date format MMYYYY first (because datevalue won't convert it to a code otherwise in the excel sheet) and for that i used `data = .Cells(iRowNo, 3) & "/" & .Cells(iRowNo, 2)` (i tested and it return the desired result that is something like 4/2017) but then i tried to convert it into a datevalue code with `datav = DateValue(data)` but it results in a full date (01/04/2017).

On the second case i tried to convert the two dates (`begin_date` and `end_date`) directly to a datevalue code with a similar code but it returned the same result (full date dd/mm/yyyy).

Seems like datevalue does not work the same way in vba as in an excel formula, at least in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A date is **always** a full date. So `4/2017` is not a date. It is either the first `2017-04-01` or last `2017-04-30` day of the month.

This is due to how Excel defines a date. A date is the amount of days since `1900-01-01` so today is day number `43675` which means `2019-07-29`. Using this definition it is not possible to find the number of days since `1900-01-01` that represent `2017-04`.

Because `2017-03-31` is `42825` and if you add `+1` then `42826` is `2017-04-01`. So you need to define for yourself that `2017-04` is either the fist or the last day of `April`.

For example if you define a expiry date `2017-04` would probably mean `2017-04-30`.

To convert a date into its `DateValue` you first need to create a real date:

```
Dim MyDate As Date
MyDate = DateSerial(2017, 4, 1)

Dim MyValue As Long
MyValue = DateValue(MyDate)

'returns 42826
```

Comment: Yes i agree with that for the first case but in the second case i already have a define date (for example ```begin_date``` = ```2017-03-31```) and the ```a = DateValue(date1)``` code didn't returned any code like ```2017-03-31``` Edit: i replied before u edited the answer

Comment: @JPAbreu you need to create a real date for `DateValue` eg using `DateSerial` see my edited answer. Never use `Strings` (which are text) as date. You cannot calculate with dates if they are actually text. This `data = .Cells(iRowNo, 3) & "/" & .Cells(iRowNo, 2)` creates only text but not a date.

Comment: Ok, just one more question: in the code you just wrote in the above answer ```Dim MyDate As Date
MyDate = DateSerial(2017, 4, 1)``` 
you define the date there but if i want to get the date from a cell in the excel sheet how could i do that? I don't have much experience in vba yet i'm sorry.

Comment: i tried to use ```MyDate = DateSerial(date1)``` date1 (date1 = .Cells(iRowNo, 2)) represents the date in the cells on the ```begin_date``` column but it doesn't work.

Comment: if the date in the cells is a **real** date not a text, then you can use `MyDate = .Cells(iRowNo, 2)` otherwise you need to split your text into `Year`, `Month` and `Day` so you can use this in `DateSerial(Year, Month, Day)`.

Comment: Nevermind i was dumb, i defined ```year```, ```month``` and ```day``` separately as ```ano_init = Year(date1), mes_init = Month(date1) ,dia_init = Day(date1)``` and then used your code ```MyDate = DateSerial(ano_init, mes_init, dia_init)``` and it worked fine.